# Jupyter NBConvert --to pdf causes undefined control sequence '\HyPsd@expand@utfvii'

Tags: pdf, jupyter-notebook, latex, export, nbconvert

Any jupyter notebook I try to export to PDF leads to an error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\HyPsd@expand@utfvii ...'.
```

I can export as webpdf but University prefers PDF where possible (page counts etc.).

I have an M1 Mac and have followed [this post](https://anik8das.medium.com/how-to-export-jupyter-notebooks-ipynb-files-on-an-m1-mac-1e54f95d1f63) to get my ipynb's to export to PDF but am stuck on the final step (`jupyter nbconvert --to pdf test.ipynb`)

I have also run `tlmgr update --all --self` to make sure it's not old versions.

I have inspected by converting ipynb to tex via `jupyter nbconvert --to latex test.ipynb` and there is no obvious issue.

Comment: Can you provide the tex file converted from ipynb here so other can understand the issue better  and help you?

Comment: how should I share it?

Comment: you can post the content of the tex file here.

Comment: Afraid to say it's too big - 1054 lines!

Comment: I would recommend you to start removing lines and check which line produces the error (which a very common method of debugging) and unfortunately unless you are giving reproducible problem here, the chance of getting help from this place is small. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice @shafee! I will see what I can do